# Random crash after several hours

Tags: raspbian, python, crash

sorry for the next error)
I'm working on a project with my rpi, which just test on a student website if a teacher is absent, or if a lesson is moved. Actually, the rpi crash totally randomly : after 7-8 hours, or even after 2 day of perfect work

He just stop, the touchscreen "softlock", and the rpi lit up the green and the red light, with no flash. He's working around 45°C and he still have 500Mo of RAM, and many Go left. The touchscreen seem to still work when i tap it, but dont respond. The only way to go out of this situation is to unplug and replug the alimentation cable.
There is only a simple keyboard connected, the symbol of undervoltage appear pretty rarely. The GPIO is only use to power on the touchscreen and the camera is connected to the rpi, but isn't use. Also the program make a "report" of is ressource every 3 minutes : he still have many RAM left, the temperature is around 45°C, the CPU isn't overused, the network is still working,
He's powered at 5V 2,1A, and he also crash with the touchscreen unplugged. It's a raspberry pi 3b.

Do you have any idea of what the problem can come from?
Thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: You need to give enough information to allow us to duplicate the error.  I.e. we need to know all the software running on the Pi.  You also need to explain exactly what you mean by crash.

Comment: The program is just automaticly start with the autostart file, and by crash, I mean he stop working, the graphical interface don't respond, the only way to fix it is to unplug and replug the alimentation cable. Chromium, lxterminal, python3 and Filezilla are basically all the main process.

Comment: @RλPHλΣʟ, most likely is that your operating system has run out of resources, such as sockets, process stack overflows etc.  To check if this is the case, you can reboot every 5 hours, say, and see the random crashes go away, ... If yes, I can try to suggest get around or possible solutions.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information you have given in the comment to the question. What Raspberry Pi model do you use? Is there any hardware attached to the USB ports that consumes power from the RasPi?

Comment: There is only a simple keyboard connected, the symbol of undervoltage appear pretty rarely. The GPIO is only use to power on the touchscreen and the camera is connected to the rpi, but isn't use. Also the program make a "report" of is ressource every 3 minutes : he still have many RAM left, the temperature is around 45°C, the CPU isn't overused, the network is still working, ...

Comment: I asked you to add information to the question. Now again you only use a comment. Please understand how this site works. Comments are mainly used to improve questions and answers. Someone you would like to help you will read the question in the first place and not the comments.

Comment: Still no idea of where the problem can come from ?